# How to handle a numeric list containing "bis" "ter" "quater" and so on

Tags: vb.net, storing-data

I need to handle a List (or Array or DataTable Field) composed by numbers where sometimes there are "bis" "ter" "quater" and so on.

The list looks like:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   3 bis
>   4
>   5
>   5 bis
>   5 ter
>   5 quater
>   6
>   ...

My idea (to preserve order) is to store data using decimals this way:

> 5 bis = 5.2
>   5 ter = 5.3
>   5 quater = 5.4

and convert to string and then use `replace` on extracting data.

**My question are:

- is this a good way?

- are there better solutions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach will break when you get to `decies` (ie `5.10`).  It may be better to create a new structured type.  For example

```
Public Structure OrderedNumber
    Public Value As Integer
    Public Order As Integer
End Structure
```

This lets you do things like :

```
Module Module1
    Public Structure OrderedNumber
        Implements IComparable(Of OrderedNumber)
        Public Value As Integer
        Public Order As Integer
        Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As OrderedNumber) As Integer _
            Implements IComparable(Of OrderedNumber).CompareTo
            If Value = other.Value Then
                Return Order - other.Order
            Else
                Return Value - other.Value
            End If
        End Function
    End Structure

    Sub Main()    
        Dim OList As New List(Of OrderedNumber)
        Dim n As OrderedNumber    
        ' 5 ter - adding out of order!
        n.Value = 5
        n.Order = 2
        OList.Add(n)
        ' 5            
        n.Order = 0
        OList.Add(n)
        ' 5 bis
        n.Order = 1
        OList.Add(n)

        OList.Sort()

        For Each n In OList
            Console.WriteLine(n.Value & ":" & n.Order)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()    
    End Sub    
End Module
```

Which outputs :

> 5:0
>   5:1
>   5:2

You can similarly work with a `Dictionary(Of OrderedNumber, MyObject)`, for example, where you want to link each item with a data object of some sort.

Comment: It seems to be a good idea (+1). I'll test it in my scenario. (Anyway to avoid break on `decies` I can use `5.02` on `bis`) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You said *composed by numbers*, but it looks like *strings*. So you can parse the strings, assuming the format is always an integer with a possible space and suffix.

You can use LINQ to query the strings. `dataDecimals` holds your resulting decimals.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dataStrings =
        {"1",
         "2",
         "3",
         "3 bis",
         "4",
         "5",
         "5 bis",
         "5 ter",
         "5 quater",
         "6"}
    For Each ds In dataStrings
        Console.WriteLine(ds)
    Next
    Dim dataDecimals =
        dataStrings.Select(
            Function(d)
                Dim s = d.Split(" "c)
                Dim r = Decimal.Parse(s(0))
                If s.Length = 2 Then
                    Select Case s(1)
                        Case "bis"
                            r += 0.2
                        Case "ter"
                            r += 0.3
                        Case "quater"
                            r += 0.4
                    End Select
                End If
                Return r
            End Function)
    For Each dd In dataDecimals
        Console.WriteLine(dd)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Console output

> 1
>   
> 2
>   
> 3
>   
> 3 bis
>   
> 4
>   
> 5
>   
> 5 bis
>   
> 5 ter
>   
> 5 quater
>   
> 6
>   
> 1
>   
> 2
>   
> 3
>   
> 3.2
>   
> 4
>   
> 5
>   
> 5.2
>   
> 5.3
>   
> 5.4
>   
> 6